Multiple graphs in same figure using matplotlib
Hello I am trying to get 3 plots in the same figure using matplotlib.
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

font = {'family' : 'Sans',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 16}

matplotlib.rc('font', **font)

x = np.arange(20,100,0.1)
p = 6
a = 2

y1 = (((x-p) ** (-p-0.1)) * ((x-a) ** (0.1+a)))/(p-a)
y2 = (((x-p) ** (-p-50)) * ((x-a) ** (50+a)))/(p-a)
y3 = (((x-p) ** (-p-200)) * ((x-a) ** (200+a)))/(p-a)

plt.plot(x, y1, linewidth=2.0, label='q = 0.1')
plt.plot(x, y2, linewidth=2.0, label='q = 50')
plt.plot(x, y3, linewidth=2.0, label='q = 200')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()

The figure I am getting is this which has the blue line invisible and the yellow line turned to a straight line:

However individually the blue line (Y1) is visible and the Yellow line (Y2) should not be a straight line.


How can I get all 3 graphs in the same figure in overlapping fashion?

Your data span vastly different scales. Consider using a log scaling.

plt.yscale("log")

Notice the scaling in the upper left of your plot. The green data (y3) has values on the order of 1e16 while the blue data (y1) has values on the order of 1e-5. Matplotlib will try and fit everything, so the scale needed to see the green data means that the other data look to be 0.
To view them all, change your y-axis scale to be log by adding the following line:
plt.yscale("log")

Then you'll get this:

Note: you have NaNs in your y3 data so the line is cut off.
